# Библиотека с готовыми регулярными выражениями JAVA

Tags: java, регулярные-выражения, library, поиск-библиотек

Существует ли библиотека с готовыми строками или методами содержащими регулярные выражения для типичных случаев?

Мне не очень нравятся регулярки прямо в коде, иногда пользуюсь апачевскими методами из commonLang3. Но тут возник вопрос, может есть уже готовые библиотеки с регулярками.
Например:
- найти мобильный номер в потоке строк

- провалидировать почту
- вытащить все скрипты из текста
- итд

Нашел вот такое решение https://github.com/VerbalExpressions/JavaVerbalExpressions
Но оно предлагает написание регулярок самому с помощью методов, интересно, но не то. Может кто знает именно набор захардкоженых регулярок на многие случаи жизни?

Comment: Захардкодьте нужные вам регулярки в свою библиотеку

Comment: @АндрейNOP спасибо, я знаю что можно все написать самому, но как говорится, многое уже давно сделано за нас.

Comment: @Виктор "многое уже давно сделано за нас". Есть замечательная либа под названием Интернет. В нем есть все регулярки которые Вам нужны.

Comment: Можете быть первым и создать такую либу.

Comment: @Tsyklop спасибо, я ей воспользовался и сейчас пользуюсь. Ведь этот сайт находится в сети Интернет и создан, чтобы можно было задать вопрос, чтобы знающие товарищи помогли.